# uiOutput and and renderUI do not work (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app creates a simple list (`actives$name`) of strings, and shows me back those strings.
For some reason, it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "name", label = "Name", value = "foo"),
      actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add")
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("activeB")
    )
  ),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  actives <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    actives$name <- c(actives$name, input$name)
  })

  output$activeB <- renderUI({
    for (i in 1:length(actives$name)) {
      p("Name:")
      verbatimTextOutput(actives$name[i])
      print(actives$name[i])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `print()` I'm using in the `for` loop shows the correct result, so it "knows" what I'm trying to do. It just doesn't output it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting one.  Took me a couple of goes to get it.  You need to wrap the `renderUI` output in a `tagList`:

```
  output$activeB <- renderUI({
    tagList(HTML(paste(actives$name, collapse="<br>")))
  })
```

Two observations:

- Your demo code would never have worked because your debug `print` loop is the last statement in `renderUI`, so `renderUI` never returns anything. :(
- You know you can get the same effect without resorting to `uiOutput` and `renderUI`, right?  I'm assuming you've simplified your actual use case to focus on the issue - in which case, thank you! :)

Full code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "name", label = "Name", value = "foo"),
      actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add")
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("activeB")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  actives <- reactiveValues(
    name=c()
  )
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    actives$name <- c(actives$name, input$name)
  })
  output$activeB <- renderUI({
    tagList(HTML(paste(actives$name, collapse="<br>")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your answer wasn't exactly what I needed, but it did clarify that `renderUI` returns the last value, and that was where my problem was. The solution using `tagList(HTML())` works, when adapted to my purposes. Regarding your second observation - that is correct.

Comment: For each "item" on my `actives` there are quite a lot of UI elements I want to draw, and the use of `paste` is spot on here.